# Same function with same signatures in the same class/struct? Overload?

Tags: c++, function, class, boost, member

I have seen a code portion in the boost example which is used to construct a state machine. What confused me is the two member functions ElapsedTime()? Is this allowed for the two functions to have the same signatures such as function name and parameters type?

I have googled a lot but without any luck to find relevant info about this. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct Active : sc::simple_state< Active, StopWatch, Stopped >
{
public:
    typedef sc::transition< EvReset, Active > reactions;

    Active() : elapsedTime_( 0.0 ) {}
    double ElapsedTime() const { return elapsedTime_; }
    double & ElapsedTime() { return elapsedTime_; }

private: 
    double elapsedTime_;
};
```

Comment: They don't have the same parameter types as one of them is `const` (which means that the implicitly passed `this` pointer is `const`). For the second it isn't.

Comment: They don't have the same signature, one is const, the other isn't

Comment: @BenjaminBannier minor correction: _the implicitly passed `this` pointer is **to** `const`_. This, of course, is what you meant.

Comment: @sehe is right of course; the relevant passage is §9.3.2/1 in C++11.

Comment: @sehe, yes, that's an important correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature of a function is defined by the name and by the argument types.
You have two functions with the same name, but they do not get the same arguments!

You might wonder how could it be?

So, each member function gets another parameter implicitly: this is the "this" pointer. A pointer to the object who called that method.

When you add const in the end of the method, you specify the "this" argument as a **const pointer to const**. In the other method (without the const), the type of "this" is just **const pointer**.

Hence, you have two methods with different signature, and there is no problem at all.

Comment: This is incorrect because `this` parameter is actually of type `const Active*` and not `const Active*const`.

Answer (score 1):

They do not have the same signatures - one is `const` and another one is not. Constness is part of member function signature.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures are different because one has `const` qualifier.
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is this allowed

This usage is allowed as [over.load#2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.load#2.2) states:

> Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list cannot be overloaded if any of them is a static member function declaration ([class.static]). Likewise, member function template declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, and the same template parameter lists cannot be overloaded if any of them is a static member function template declaration. The types of the implicit object parameters constructed for the member functions for the purpose of overload resolution ([over.match.funcs]) are not considered when comparing parameter-type-lists for enforcement of this rule. In contrast, **if there is no static member function declaration among a set of member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list, then these member function declarations can be overloaded if they differ in the type of their *implicit object parameter*.** [ Example: The following illustrates this distinction:

(end quote)

Now, in your example the first overload has a `const` qualifer which means that its *implicit object parameter* has type `const Active&` while the second overload has no `const` qualifer meaning that its *implicit object parameter* is of type `Active&`. Moroever, there is no static member function declaration for `ElapsedTime` with the same paremeer-type-list. Hence using the above quoted statement, this means that the given usage is allowed.

##### Note

Note that the currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22912982/12002570) is technically incorrect because it claims that `this` is a *const pointer to const*. But in reality the standard [specifies](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.this#1) that inside a `const` qualified member function the `this` pointer is of type `const X*` while inside a non-const qualified member function the `this` pointer is of type `X*`.